# Using javascript to detect if a word is unavailable...?

Tags: javascript

I have been using javascript to remove or replace certain words from an RSS feed using the following code:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace( /Words to be removed/g, "Words to be replaced");
```

I was wondering if there was a way to detect a certain word and display a message if it does not exist?

Comment: What do you mean does not exist? Not in the dictionary? or doesn't appear in the HTML of the feed?

Comment: As in it doesn't appear in the HTML of the feed.
Sorry, I should of been a little more clearer.

Answer (score 2):

In a similar manner as you have used, you can use the `match` method.

```
var matches = document.body.innerHTML.match(/Word to detect/g);
```

If there are any matches you'll get an array of values that matched.

```
if(matches.length > 0)
   alert("Found!");
```

Something like this should work for you.

Comment: Thank you! Thats the kind of thing that I am looking for. But for some reason I get the alert if my word is displayed or not...

Comment: Could you post a JsFiddle with some sample of what you are searching for and the RSS feed?

Answer (score 0):

If your regex matches a number of words, I think one possibility here would be to replace the second argument to `.replace()` with a function. Then, you can implement some counting yourself based on the word that was replaced.

```
replacedCounts = {};
"bunch of words".replace(/(bunch|of|words)/, function(replaced) {

  var prevCount = replacedCounts[replaced];
  if (!prevCount) { prevCount = 0; }
  replacedCounts[replaced] = prevCount + 1;
  return "replacement string";

}); // result should be: "replacement string replacement string replacement string "
// you can now consult replacedCounts['bunch'], etc, to see how many of each were replaced.
```

Depending on your exact usage, Praveen's answer may be more useful.